# php after scrolling to bottom of the page, message in a div is not being executed

Tags: php, html

I have a contact form in PHP. After a mail has been sent I wanted the functionality of scroll to the bottom of the page so that user can see whether mail has been sent or not. If a mail has been sent/failed to send we get a error message using an alert class for div. However here the after the page scrolls to the bottom I'm unable to see the alert box but if I remove the scroll to bottom functionality i'm able to see the alert message even after the mail has been sent. Can anyone guide me on where i'm wrong.

```
<?php
//validation done here
 if(mail($toEmail, $subject, $body, $headers)){
                    // Email Sent
                    $msg = 'Your email has been sent';
                    $msgClass = 'alert-success';

                } else {
                    // Failed
                    $msg = 'Your email was not sent';
                    $msgClass = 'alert-danger';

                }
                header('Location:index.php#bottomOfPage');
?>


 //remaining html goes here 
    <?php if($msg != ''): ?>

        <div class="alert <?php echo $msgClass; ?>"><?php echo $msg; ?></div>

    <?php endif; ?>
    <a name="bottomOfPage"></a>
    //form is here
```

Comment: is this all of your code? your line header("Location....") actually refreshes the page/redirects the user to index.php but that means your $msg isnt here anymore.. you can either save the msg and msgClass in a session and do it with if($_SESSION["msg"] != "") OR you send the email via ajax and display the result after your call..

Comment: Thanks  Christopher Supertramp, it worked

Answer (score 0):

```
Please move the 'bottomOfPage' name tag above the success/failure message displaying
Try the code like below

<a name="bottomOfPage"></a>
<?php if($msg != ''): ?>

        <div class="alert <?php echo $msgClass; ?>"><?php echo $msg; ?></div>

    <?php endif; ?>
```